# Display image in view from URL of image in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My controller returns a string which is a url of an image. How do I display that url on the view in asp.net mvc 4

I guess it's something very straight forward but I can't find out how to do it.

Comment: Show you controller & view.

Comment: You should be more specific. Did you pass some model to your view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not providing a lot of detail but if you have the image url in the controller you should be able to set it to a model property and then in the view use something like:

```
<img src="@Html.Raw(model.ImageUrl)" alt="a description of the image">
```

to use that url to display the image.  Yes?